# Spell checking in editor using xamarin.forms application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, editor, spell-checking

I am developing a chat application using Xamarin.Forms. I have a requirement of spell checking. I am using an `Editor` to enter the message.

In `Editor` If user types something it has to check the spelling of the word and inform the user that spelling is wrong with an underline or something(ike Grammarly does in web). How can I achieve this using Xamarin.Forms.

I have tried with Xamarin.Forms default property `IsSpellCheckEnabled` but it doesn't effect anything i.e It doesn't check the spellings. Is there any workaround to achieve this. In the below image the wrong spelled word is underlined with blue color. I want to do it like this but don't have any idea on how to achieve this. Can anyone please help me with this. Thank you.

[image: Here is the image showing what I want to achieve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Keyboard disables spell checking, `IsSpellCheckEnabled` property is ignored. So try to enable spell check first from your device. For more info visit [docs.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/editor). Sample code

```
<Editor AutoSize="TextChanges" IsSpellCheckEnabled="True" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
</Editor>
```

**Note:** If in your keypad *auto correct* option in enabled, after hitting enter/space wrong spelling would correct automatic and it wouldn't show you underline text.

**Update:** Also set `IsTextPredictionEnabled="True"` in your `Editor`.

> If a Keyboard has been set that disables spell checking, such as
>   Keyboard.Chat, the IsSpellCheckEnabled property is ignored. Therefore,
>   the property cannot be used to enable spell checking for a Keyboard
>   that explicitly disables it.

[image]

Comment: ,Thank you for the response.I'm using normal keyboard i.e.,Keyboard="Default" and spell check property is enabled in my device settings but still it is not working don't know what's wrong.Here is my code `<Editor x:Name="Message"  PlaceholderColor="Gray" IsSpellCheckEnabled="True" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="{Binding MessageText}"/>`

Comment: Are you typing or setting text programatically? you should type.

Comment: I'm typing only..I've binded my text to some variable in my view model and not setting the text programatically

Comment: Try to set `IsTextPredictionEnabled="True"` and check.

Comment: Thank you,That's working with IsSpellCheckEnabled="True" property in case of normal editor but in the case of customeditor it's not working,have to set the properties in renderer

Comment: CGPA6.4,.Thank you ,I've written a custom render for the editor so I've to set the spellcheck property in that render,Do you know how to set this property ?? I've tried it in the renderer but there is property/method that's accepting spellcheck property

Comment: Same I think `Editor.IsTextPredictionEnabledProperty`.